# New to Python, wondering if creating a specific graphic is possible

Tags: python, graphics

I'm brand new to Python (as in I just started looking at it today). My only other coding experience is in Matlab and a little bit in R. I can't do what I want to in Matlab, so I'm wondering if Python is the tool I need. I want to make a graphic similar to what is seen here: https://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/charts-climate-change-bar-codes-1.4802293

I have a matrix of weather data which I would use to create the colour values. Is something like this possible in Python, and if so could someone help me with finding some resources to learn how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: We are not here to do anything for you. Please first read the documentation or tutorial, there are alot out there. StackOverflow should be the last place where you're going to ask help. If you did that, please edit your post in order to add a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you tried so far and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: Have a look at the [tag:python] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info). It has resources.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do this in Python. I would look at visualization libraries such as plotly or matplotlib. Go to their websites, follow their tutorials and I'm sure you'll have a better idea then on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems ur looking to get some good visualizations, i bet you could start with visualization packages in python. Like ggplot2 in R, python has matplotlib, and seaborn libraries which can greatly help you to achieve this. Below are some resources you can look at : For matplotlib follow this : https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html
and for seaborn : https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html

Hope this helps!